# Bootstrap navbar isn't expanding or showing menu items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I'm a graphic designer who started coding a few weeks ago to hopefully move into front end stuff. This sample website I'm building isn't cooperating in the navbar area. I have it set up nicely in all my desktop views, but when it collapses, I can't seem to get it to work. It won't expand or show menu items. I looked up everything I could, but I just got different types of navbars with the same problem. I'm using Brackets.

Any help at all is appreciated, even if you see something unrelated I'm bugging up.

Thank you!

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>loot</title>
    <meta name="description" content="fast and personal messenger delivery service">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div  class="container">
        <div  class="jumbotron header">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-right" role = "navigation">
           <div class = "navbar-header">
              <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
                 data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
                 <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
           </div>

           <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
              <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href= "#">Merch</a></li>
                 <li><div class="btn btn-primary">Schedule a pickup</div></li>
                 <li><div class="btn btn-success">Schedule a delivery</div></li>
              </ul>

           </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my CSS

```
.header {
    background-color: #46B4CE !important;
    background:  url(images/loot-whiteArtboard%201@0.75x.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 30%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 20em;
}

/*extra small devices*/
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .header {
    background-size: 55%;
    height: 15em;
  }
}
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .header {
        background-size: 40%;
    }
}
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .header {
        background-size: 30%;
    }
}

.btn{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:8px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

[fullscreen view of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UMUh.png)

[mobile view not able to be expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YFH4.png)

Comment: my guess is that you'll need to add the bootstrap.js as well, or at least that's what I have done on sites I've written (and the Bootstrap examples have it included in the HTML for theirs)

Comment: @NeilStockon thanks for the tip! I added it in there and it still doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: i think you forget -  jquery library file

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wodfx0r5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add bootstrap js and jquery min js to work nav menu.

```css
  .header {
    background-color: #46B4CE !important;
    background:  url(images/loot-whiteArtboard%201@0.75x.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 30%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 20em;
}

/*extra small devices*/
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .header {
    background-size: 55%;
    height: 15em;
  }
}
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .header {
        background-size: 40%;
    }
}
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .header {
        background-size: 30%;
    }
}

.btn{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:8px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>loot</title>
    <meta name="description" content="fast and personal messenger delivery service">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div  class="container">
        <div  class="jumbotron header">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-right" role = "navigation">
           <div class = "navbar-header">
              <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
                 data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
                 <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
           </div>

           <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
              <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href= "#">Merch</a></li>
                 <li><div class="btn btn-primary">Schedule a pickup</div></li>
                 <li><div class="btn btn-success">Schedule a delivery</div></li>
              </ul>

           </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I feel so silly now, I spent like 2 hours on this haha. But it worked! Thank you so much. Do I have to style the collapsed menu any differently, or will the style be the same for both?

Comment: Most Welcome! :) And yes you can do style differently like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vp7XS/