# Why won't my navbar toggle button work on my phone?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

(I have no experience or knowledge about javascript or jQuery) I was making a navbar for my website
and it was working fine on my laptop so I decided to check it on my phone too. When I opened my website I saw my navbar with the title and nav-bar toggle button. When I clicked on the button nothing happened. Here's my nav code :`

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>smekiron</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" data-abc="true">ASHVA VENTURES WORLDWIDE |</a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" data-abc="true">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="category.html" data-abc="true">SHOP BY CATEGORY</a> </li>
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="otherproducts.html" data-abc="true">OTHER PRODUCTS</a> </li>
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="certifications.html" data-abc="true">CERTIFICATIONS</a> </li>
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html" data-abc="true">ABOUT US</a> </li>
<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#contact" data-abc="true">CONTACT</a> </li>
</ul>
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"> <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"> <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="material-icons instant-search__icon">search</i></button> </form>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **bootstrap js** and **jquery js** links script to let the bootstrap nav works correctly.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This question might be a duplicate of this question -> [Bootstrap navbar isn't expanding or showing menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454672/bootstrap-navbar-isnt-expanding-or-showing-menu-items)